# How to prevent overriding array entries in a for-loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, for-loop

I got the hint for my program to make it easier to read and maintenance with using class structures instead of a mass of arrays and matrices. (I didn't find similar topics here, but maybe I used the wrong vocabulary. But although I hope to get help)

As I have a dataset with multiple entries I don't wanna have all of them but some specific ones. So I build a class to store them easier:

```
public class ControlPoint
{
    // classify necessary variables
    public double _collimatorangle;
    public double _gantryangle;
    public double[] _jawpositions = new double[4];
    public double _monitorunits;
    public double[] _mlcs = new double[120];
    public double _beamenergy;

    // construct the class
    public ControlPoint()
    {

    }
}
```

Calling and filling them is not the problem but I have over 100 of those `ControlPoint` objects, so I wanted to use a for loop to fill them and store them in a new array/list/ArrayList. In the end, I would like to use the data for calculating differences but converting this class into double doesn't work. So I wrote this

```
ControlPoint[] DataPoints = new ControlPoint[160];
ControlPoint CoPos = new ControlPoint();

for (int j = 0; j < 160; j++)
{
    // reading data from file
    // ...
    CoPos._jawpositions[0] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_1);
    CoPos._jawpositions[1] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_2);
    CoPos._jawpositions[2] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_3);
    CoPos._jawpositions[3] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_4);

    DataPoints[j] = CoPos;
}
```

So after the loop, I expected a `DataPoints` array with different values for each array entry. But in Debugging I saw that changing the data e.g. at `j = 10` all values in `DataPoints` from 0 to 9 change to the actual value.

I don't know where I did a wrong step and hope you can help me to prevent that overriding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only creating one instance of `ControlPoint` and modifying it over and over, then assigning it to every element of the array. Move the instantiation inside the loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 160; j++)
{
    ControlPoint CoPos = new ControlPoint();

    // reading data from file
    // ...
    CoPos._jawpositions[0] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_1);
    CoPos._jawpositions[1] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_2);
    CoPos._jawpositions[2] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_3);
    CoPos._jawpositions[3] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_4);

    DataPoints[j] = CoPos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the same CoPos object to every element in your DataPoints array, only altering the value on every loop. Create a new object inside the loop:

```
ControlPoint[] DataPoints = new ControlPoint[160];

for (int j = 0; j < 160; j++)
{
    // reading data from file
    // ...
    var CoPos = new ControlPoint();

    CoPos._jawpositions[0] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_1);
    CoPos._jawpositions[1] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_2);
    CoPos._jawpositions[2] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_3);
    CoPos._jawpositions[3] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadData_4);

    DataPoints[j] = CoPos;
}
```